# NSTextField outer cell background inside custom draw view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4

I'm struggling with an NSTextField background issue. The textfield is within a custom view that has a semi-transparent black background. I've tried subclassing the field, the field's cell and a few other things to no avail. I'm getting this clearColor background outside of the text field cell. I'm looking for basically just a black NSSearchFeld, not having much luck though.

here is what i'm getting[image]

I basically just want a textfield with a rounded stroke which blends into the black background.

thanks all, i'm fairly new to Xdev

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, I needed to have the custom NSView subclass I'm using to draw the window use
[self bounds] when drawing vs the dirtyRect passed to the drawrect method.